# Modifying error messages for Command Objects embedded in controller

Tags: grails

I am trying to modify the messages.properties file for form input validated by a Command Object that is in specified in the controller.  The output I get from the standard error message (that I modified slightly to assure I was hitting that specific one) is:

email cannot be empty test class com.dashboard.RegisterController$DashboardUserRegistrationCommand

but no variant of com.dashboard.RegisterController$DashboardUserRegistrationCommand.null.message
works

I am wondering what the correct specification should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put DashboardUserRegistrationCommand outside (below) of RegisterController but still in the same file. Then **com.dashboard.DashboardUserRegistrationCommand..** should work.

i.e. *com.dashboard.DashboardUserRegistrationCommand.message.nullable*

Answer (score 0):

The typical layout of error messages is:

```
${packageName}.${className}.${propertyName}.${errorCode}
```

So for your example it would be:

```
com.dashboard.DashboardUserRegistrationCommand.message.nullable
```

In the [Grails Reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/) on the right hand side there is a header titled 'Constraints'.  On each page of the specific constraints listed under that header the `${errorCode}` value is listed at the bottom of the page.

And sometimes you have to restart a `run-app` to get new messages to populate in a Grails project.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help others in the future, I had the same issues and my problem was the way I was defining my key, I use now:

For default messages:
default.null.message=Write a value for {0}

For commmand error messages:
my.package.UserCommand.name.nullable=Please tell us your name

It is strange that sometimes you use nullable and sometimes you use null. The best thing is going to the Grails Constraints directly and check how is it done for example:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/nullable.html